# MPAndroidChart remove legend

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library and I want to remove the values in in the top right corner of the `PieChart`, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The values you are talking about belong to the [Legend](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/legend/).

To disable them (prevent them from being displayed), call

```
Legend l = chart.getLegend();
l.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: On the new release you should use

    `chart.setDrawLegend(false);`

Comment: This was the old release :-)

Comment: how to hide specific legend means legend for dataset3?

Answer (score 1):

you can set like this

```
linechart.setData();
...
linechert.getLegend().setEnable(false);
```

gone Legend should be at the back of setData()

Answer (score 0):

try     `pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false)`

Comment: no , this would remove the x-Values from inside of pie, but we have a list of x-Values in the top right corner of the pie Chart , and under this list we have the pie chart Label , i want to remove this List and the Label

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into xml file:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pie_chart">
</com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart>
```

Write this into .java file:

```
pieChart = findViewById(R.id.pie_chart);
     
Legend l = pieChart.getLegend();
l.setEnabled(false);
```